# How do I install Insight Debugger on ubuntu 15.10 64 bit

Tags: apt, 15.10, debugging

I was trying to install insight debugger in ubuntu 15.10 64 bit. Here's what I did:

First I opened `/etc/apt/sources.list` in gedit

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then I add these two line at the end of the file

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/sevenmachines/dev/ubuntu natty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/sevenmachines/dev/ubuntu natty main
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

finally I tried to install insight

```
sudo apt-get install insight
```

but this gives me an error
here's the original error message

```
(Reading database ... 238526 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../insight_6.8.1-0ubuntu0~sevenmachines1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking insight (6.8.1-0ubuntu0~sevenmachines1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/insight_6.8.1-0ubuntu0~sevenmachines1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libinproctrace.so', which is also in package gdbserver 7.10-1ubuntu2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/insight_6.8.1-0ubuntu0~sevenmachines1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What can I do for this error? Is there anyway I can install insight?

Comment: It seems that `insight` conflicts with `gdbserver` (they install the same file). Have you tried uninstalling the latter?

Comment: I tried but then It tried to replace a file owned by gdb I can't remove gdb. But I could successfully install insight on 14.04 32 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for helping me on this problem. I think I found a solution for this error.
Thanks "fkraiem" for giving the hint.
This is my solution

First of all I backed up the files insight trying to overwrite
(this should be done as root)

```
su 
mv /usr/lib/libinproctrace.so /home/(usrname)/Desktop/libinproctrace.so
mv /usr/bin/gdb-add-index /home/(username)/Desktop/gdb-add-index
```

Then I removed `gdbserver` which owns the file `/usr/liblibinproctrace.so`:

```
sudo apt-get remove gdbserver
```

But the insight tried to replace file `/usr/bin/gdb-add-index` belonging to `gdb`. So I removed gdb too:

```
sudo apt-get remove gdb
```

then I installed insight

```
sudo apt-get install insight
```

It successfully executed but I can't use `insight` because I removed `gdb` so I had to re-install `gdb` but I can't do it because now `gdb` is trying to replace those 2 files now belonging to `insight`. So I deleted them (it's OK because I backed up original files) (as root) and then I installed gdb:

```
rm /usr/bin/gdb-add-index /usr/lib/libinproctrace.so
sudo apt-get install gdb
```

It was successful. Check if `gdb-add-index` & `libinproctrace.so` exist in their default folders. If not, copy the backed up files.

Finally,

```
su
gedit /usr/bin/gdb-add-index
```

and add this snippet to file and save

```
gdb --batch-silent -ex "file $file" -ex "save gdb-index $dir"

if test -f "${file}.gdb-index"; then
   objcopy --add-section .gdb_index="${file}.gdb-index" --set-section-flags .gdb_index=readonly "$file" "$file"
    rm -f "${file}.gdb-index"
fi
```

*This snippet was the `gdb-add-index` installed by insight. I don't know what it do but I copied it into the gdb's `gdb-add-index`.